# How to add webform to existing content type?

Tags: nodes, webforms

I have installed [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) and would like to add it to my custom content type. I have checked my content type under `admin/config/content/webform` and saved the webform settings but I still don't get the option to add a `webform` to my content type.

Comment: `clear cache` and check again if it works. and which version of webform are you using, make sure it is latest because I am not able replicate such issue in mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Content type edit page : /admin/structure/types/manage/[ContentTypeName]. There you can see the `webform` under the `Menu Settings`. Just enable it from there. Adding screenshot :

[image]

Comment: I don't see this tab on content type edit form even after enabling  webform_node submodule using 8.x-5.0-beta9

Answer (score 2):

To add a webform to your content type you should add a field to your content type and choose other as a type of this field ---> Reference /other then save after that when you choose the type of reference you must choose webform and save
Now in your content type when you add content you find a field for your webform and in that you put one of your webform